# Extending object member of subclass

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop

I'm building [Page Objects](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/) for my automated tests, and I'm doing something like this:

```ts
abstract class Page  {
  selectors: {
    // Here are selectors which are common to all my pages
    genericSelector: "...",
    commonContainer: {
      aButton: "..."
    }
  }

  // methods that are common to all my pages
}
```

```ts
class MyPage extends Page {
  
  // Here I want my page specific selectors
  // *plus* my generic selectors 
  selectors: {
    ...this.selectors,
    mySpecificSelector: "..."
  }
}
```

The above code works fine at run-time: I can correctly use all my selectors in my code. However, Typescript complains on `MyPage.ts` that:

```
Property 'selectors' in type 'MyPage' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Page.
```

Basically because TS doesn't know that I'm spreading the base class prop into the subclass.

Now, the following is what I tried:

#### One additional note

My type for the selector property looks like this:

```ts
type Selector = string | SelectorFactory | { selector: string, type: "css" | "xpath" }
type SelectorFactory = (...args: any[]) => string;
type SelectorTree = { [k: string]: SelectorTree | Selector }
```

<kbd>[Convenient TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwD2AnKBeKBnY6AlgHYDmUAPrAsmugGICGKGIlUA3njS+gFx4CJUgBoooSAIBESXLinspADzCNgACwUBfAFATocRLya82OABQA6a43SlcAxsRABtALoBKbAD5BRMgDceuAGPHQAKugQ0DhcLgDWAvj+pG4ChrQYkdHsGbxQujqMAEbJzMBQSPCMclAACoykEADyxQBWtJw6UNxGdA7UfVlRMZxaUDWDmejZEDqFVTW49Y3QHN2908uxGz3AEPjSUhtaQYX6K00AksT4TkijN3fED+EhADz6qABmlxDeOh0i1qMAArsUGk0oBAlPtiAATZaQtYbXBhDADPIREbYLo9HrWSwaQi4SxooboZaTZFPYD3CAuKTkrZSNwiXZQb6oVDSYq2KTs-FQVCQYgCcxeLC+KTHHq6BaoW4VMC44gQADusHByIlQR0YDJ6MplhFEGIEp0QA)</kbd>

## What I tried

### First attempt

```ts
class MyPage extends Page {
  selectors: {
    ...this.selectors as InstanceType<typeof Page>["selectors"]
  }
}
```

This, then complains:

```
'selectors' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

So I have to do:

```ts
  selectors: SelectorTree = // ...
```

Then I'm back to square one, as it complains that it is missing some properties from the base class. If I add `: SelectorTree` to my base class, it then doesn't complain, but I don't get proper intellisense and I even get errors (for example if I try to call a function from my selectors properties, I can't).

### Second attempt

I could, I guess, have my `selectors` member of the base `Page` class be static. Then I could do:

```ts
  selectors: {
    ...Page.selectors,
    mySpecificSelector: "..."
  }
```

This works, but, well, I now actually have an extra static member that I did not want to have.

### Third attempt, aka “I give up”

I could separate the members and have something like `baseSelectors` on my `Page` class and then I could either use them as they are within the sub-class, or spread them into my `selectors` object.

But this feels like a defeat.

Comment: This looks like a design limitation in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#33899](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33899).  Not sure what the best workaround is.

Answer (score 2):

This unfortunately seems to be a design limitation in TypeScript, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#33899](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33899):

> Due to architectural constraints around how trees are marked as checked, this has to be treated as a circular reference despite the type assertion.

Apparently any reference to `this.selectors`, no matter how indirect, seems to cause a circularity error.  So far, the only workaround I've found that gives you the right types without having to refactor the emitted code is to widen `this` to `Page` (note: `InstanceType<typeof Page>` is the same as `Page`) to get a non-`any` type for `this.selectors`, and then just brute-force suppressing the circularity warning with [`//@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments):

```
class SubPage extends Page {
  //@ts-ignore circularity warning
  selectors = { ...(this as Page).selectors, foo: "bar", open: () => "" }
}
```

You can verify that instances of `SubPage` behave as expected:

```
const p = new SubPage();
p.selectors;
// SubPage.selectors: {
//   foo: string;
//   open: () => string;
//   test: string;
// }
p.selectors.open().toUpperCase(); // okay
```

That works! But...

**⚠ ALERT ⚠**  I feel very uneasy whenever someone suggests `//@ts-ignore` because if the suppressed error has any other unpleasant effects on your code, they will still exist.  I didn't see any such effects with the example code above, but I can't be certain they're not there.  If your automobile mechanic addressed a lit "check engine" indicator light by covering the indicator light so that you can't see it anymore, you'd maybe want to start looking around to find a different mechanic, if only for a second opinion.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgKozpQAuAgsACYCSA5sAPYBOyBhRJPAwgoUJAAUQbPgMFIoEDBHi0e4gLx458pLWi0AXEgBEJnUQC+Abh2X8O4aPEBlAK4AjKTKQQAHvrM4t6yukgA9OEAArRQALQAlhw8yPAJ3PBuItwJtACeSADuINzACcBsFgpKKmrcmnhIAHQtABS0ABYJ4qKS0hAAlE2KyqrqADRIAGacnMYmHiUmk5wwEMDGrQNIGgB8piZI9vL2jpzAdEgwO8QQhUjuXv1btvIwwzVj9U2r61tNaioa24AGFRBAXhFwkhOABrEB5BxWByWIA)

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and lol at `InstanceType<typeof Page>`, I thought there was a difference between the type of an instantiated class and just the class itself. Anyhow, I'm wondering, why does `(this as Page).selectors` shows correct intellisense, while `this.selectors as Page["selectors"]` doesn't? Have any idea?

And yea, by the way the problem I see with `@ts-ignore` is that my selector object is now not typechecked anymore and I can put whatever I want there.

Comment: What do you mean you can put anything you want there?  Can you show me?

Comment: But that's an unrelated issue, right?  Look [at this code](https://tsplay.dev/1WGoKW) where I've removed `//@ts-ignore`.  This new issue has to do with TypeScript's assignability rules being slightly unsound (`{x: string, y: number}` is assignable to `{x: string}` which is assignable to `{[k: string]: string}`, but `{x: string, y: number}` is not assignable to `{[k: string]: string}`.  It's possibly worthy of a separate question (although the answer is "that's just how it works, sorry") but doesn't seem in scope here.

Comment: Oh man, you're right. But I'm not sure the explanation is correct: actually, it seems that if I the "grandchild" class is not inheriting the `SelectorTree` constraints from the grandparent at all. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/jwgp9N). This confuses me, and I'm still confused by the difference between `(this as Page)` and the alternative. But yea, I'd say in this case `// @ts-ignore` answers my specific question, with exactly the caveat that you mentioned. I'm going to upvote the answer, but we'll see if that second mechanic you mentioned shows up ;)